# Swift: How to make async calls (appending to an array) run serially?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

**The Issue**

I am running into an issue where I have a loop of network calls (called `grabImage`), all appending their callback data to the same array, and am correctly using a dispatch group to not leave the function until all network calls are done (until the group's enters/leaves are balanced). However, I have no control over the order in which the callbacks edit the aforementioned array, and am getting random orderings in the data. How do I ensure these callbacks, all occurring in separate threads, run serially to keep an ordering in the global array?

**What I’ve tried**

I have tried the obvious of using a serial queue, however, because the `grabImage` function escapes itself, I think the serial queue might think that it’s done executing before it enters the callback

**Relevant Code**

```swift
//function to grab the uploaded pics of a user and store them
func fetchAllImages(_ userPicArray: [String?], _ completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> ()) {
    var images: [UIImage] = [] //array these async calls are appending to
    for photoLink in userPicArray {
        //if the picture (link) exists
        if photoLink != nil {
            //make sure to append to the array asynchronously

            appendImagesSQ.sync { //my attempt to run serially

                //grab image and add it to the resImages array
                self.grabImage(photoLink!) { (image) in //grabImage itself escapes
                    self.grabImageDispatchGroup.leave()
                    images.append(image)
                }

            }
        }
    }
    grabImageDispatchGroup.notify(queue: grabImageSQ) {
        completion(images)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `append`. That is shuffling the array. Why not just pass the current index number down the chain so that each image is slotted into the correct index when it arrives?

Comment: A bigger picture question: What are these images used for? If for presentation in a collection view or table view, I would not suggest a design where the UI needs to wait for them all to download. Often we’d request them in a just-in-time manner, to avoid delays waiting for downloads of lots of assets. Hey, if you have some other need where downloading them all, as well as holding them all in RAM, is necessary, but for most use-cases, this is not the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making them run sequentially is not the best way to solve this problem. Sure, you’ll get them in order, but it will go much slower than you want. Instead, launch them concurrently, store the results in a dictionary, and then when you’re all done, retrieve the results from the dictionary in order, e.g.

```
func fetchAllImages(_ userPicArray: [String?], _ completion: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> ()) {
    var images: [String: UIImage] = [:] //dictionary these async calls are inserted to

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    let photoLinks = userPicArray.compactMap { $0 }
    for photoLink in photoLinks {
        group.enter()
        grabImage(photoLink) { image in
            images[photoLink] = image
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let sortedImages = photoLinks.compactMap { images[$0] }
        completion(sortedImages)
    }
}
```

By the way, it looks like your `grabImage` returns a non-optional. But what if the request failed? You still need to call the completion handler. Make sure `grabImage` calls the closure even if no image was retrieved (e.g. make the image property optional and call the closure regardless of success or failure).

Also, does `grabImage` call its completion handler on the main queue? If not, you’ll want to make sure it’s called on a serial queue, to ensure thread-safety, or else some synchronization of this `images` dictionary will be needed.

Comment: Great catch with the grabImage return type, I decided to just return a default image on grab failure - no optional needed.

Comment: I personally would recommend a closure type of `(Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void`. I would do that, or optionals. But, hey, whatever works for you. But the key is to call the closure regardless, giving the caller enough information to know what to do. But it sounds like you’ve gotten the idea. Good luck and happy coding.